# C++ calling a function from a vector of function pointers inside a class where the function definition is in main

Tags: c++, class, function, pointers, vector

Alright, in my main i have:

```
void somefunction();
int main()
{
    //bla bla bla
    SomeClass myclass = SomeClass();
    void(*pointerfunc)() = somefunction;
    myclass.addThingy(pointerfunc);

    //then later i do
    myclass.actionWithDiffrentOutcomes();
}

void somefunction()
{
    //some code
}
```

and in the class:

```
class SomeClass()
{
    public:
        void addThingy(void (*function)());
        void actionWithDiffrentOutcomes();
    private:
        std::vector<void (**)()> vectoroffunctions;
}
SomeClass::addThingy(void (*function)())
{
    vectoroffunctions.push_back(&function);
}
SomeClass::actionWithDiffrentOutcomes()
{
    (*vectoroffunctions[0])();;
}
```

I'm sort of new-ish to pointers, but I read over my c++ books, googled, ext. and this seems correct, compiles, runs but when I call "actionWithDiffrentOutcomes()" I get an access violation. I'm not sure what to do. it seems correct, but something is obviously wrong. So how can I call a function from within a class when the definition is in another?

I'm doing it this way because i cannot hard-code every option into a switch statement.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't compile; could you please double check the syntax and edit your question?

Comment: This code won't compile. Please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. Your vector is mistakenly holding pointers to pointers to functions rather than simply pointers to functions. `addThingy` is adding the address of the `function` pointer in to the `vector`, but that pointer goes out of scope in the next line.

Change your code as follows:

```
//Store pointers to functions, rather than
//pointers to pointers to functions
std::vector<void (*)()> vectoroffunctions;

SomeClass::addThingy(void (*function)())
{
    //Don't take the address of the address:
    vectoroffunctions.push_back(function);
}
```

Also, you have a lot of syntax errors in the rest of the code which should stop the code from even compiling.

Comment: Ah thank you, that makes more sense. Also, sorry about the syntax, I copied it into np++ to post it here rather then post my entire program.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is here:

```
vectoroffunctions.push_back(&function);
```

You're adding address of the **local** variable. The local variable gets destroyed once you return from the function. The address which the vector stores points to a destroyed object which is why you get *"access violation"* error at runtime.

To fix this, do this:

First change this

```
std::vector<void (**)()> vectoroffunctions;
```

to this:

```
std::vector<void (*)()> _functions; //vector of function-pointer-type
                                    //I changed the name also!
```

which is practically same as:

```
std::vector<void()> _functions; //vector of function-type
```

Now do this:

```
_functions.push_back(function); //add copy!
```

---

To make it more flexible, you could use template along with `std::function` as:

```
class A
{
    public:
        template<typename Function>
        void add(Function && fn) 
        {  
            _functions.push_back(std::forward<Function>(fn)); 
        }
        void invoke_all()
        {
           for(auto && fn : _functions)
                fn();
        }
    private:
        std::vector<std::function<void()>> _functions;
};
```

Now you can use it to store functions as well as functors:

```
void myfunction() { std::cout << "myfunction" << std::endl ; }

struct myfunctor
{
       void operator()() { std::cout << "myfunctor" << std::endl ; }
};

A a;
a.add(myfunction);   //add function
a.add(myfunctor());  //add functor!
a.invoke_all();
```

Output ([Online Demo](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c96b4d51c9ac8b90cd4f69be1cd767b6)):

```
myfunction
myfunctor
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Any elegant solution for functions with variable arguments?

Comment: @sid: What is the use case?

Comment: How would you cleanup? you add functions / functors, but what to do when class object is destroyed ?

Answer (score 1):

Function pointers are much more legible with `typedefs`:

```
typedef void (*RequiredFunction)();
```

Then you can declare `addThingy()` like this:

```
    void addThingy(RequiredFunction function);
```

And `vectoroffunctions` like so:

```
    std::vector<RequiredFunction> vectoroffunctions;
```

The definition of `addThingy` will be:

```
void SomeClass::addThingy(RequiredFunction function)
{
    vectoroffunctions.push_back(function);
}
```

And your `main()` would look more like:

```
int main()
{
    SomeClass sc;
    RequiredFunction pointerfunc = somefunction;
    sc.addThingy(pointerfunc);
    sc.actionWithDiffrentOutcomes();
}
```

Far fewer `*`s and `&`s with which to make mistakes!