# How to declare a vector of functions (lambdas)

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have seen how to declare a vector of functions (see [calling a function from a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128444/c-calling-a-function-from-a-vector-of-function-pointers-inside-a-class-where-t)).

But that answer users pointers. How can I create a vector of functions/lambdas using the new syntax in modern C++?

the examples of functions using the new syntax typically use auto:

```
auto f = [] (std::string msg) -> void { 
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
};
```

What is the actual type of f? so I can declare a vector of this type?

thank you very much for any help

Comment: "*What is the actual type of f?*" Unnameable. "*so I can declare a vector of this type?*" Yes, but it wouldn't help, because lambdas are not default-constructible. `std::vector<std::function<void(std::string)>>` will probably suit your purposes.

Comment: you can actually still use pointers if the lambda has no closures, btw

Comment: If you don't need a vector (i.e. if the actual lambdas are known at compile time) you could create a std::tuple of lambdas.

Comment: I did something similar, in a library: https://github.com/shirayukikitsune/SceneGraph/blob/master/SceneGraph/Base/Callback.h

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `std::function` with the corresponding type:

```
std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> vec;
vec.push_back([]()->void{});
```

In your case it would be `std::function<void(std::string)>`.

The exact type of a lambda is meaningless per standard ([expr.prim.lambda]/3):

> The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Another option is to use function pointers, if the lambdas have no captures.

Answer (score 10):

> What is the actual type of `f`? so I can declare a vector of this type?

Type of `f` can only be deduced by using `auto`. You can declare a `vector` of this type using

```
std::vector<decltype(f)> v;
```

However, it is not very useful. Lambda functions that look strikingly similar have different types. To make matters worse, lambda functions that have identical body also have different types.

```
auto f = [] (std::string msg) -> void { 
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
};

auto g = [] (std::string msg) -> void { 
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
};

auto h = [] (std::string msg) -> void { 
    std::cout << msg << '+' << msg << std::endl;
};
```

Given the above functions, you can't use

```
std::vector<decltype(f)> v;
v.push_back(f);  // OK
v.push_back(g);  // Not OK
v.push_back(h);  // Not OK
```

Your best option is to create a `std::vector` of `std::function`s. You can add the lambda functions to that `std::vector`. Given the above definitions of `f` and `g`, you can use:

```
std::vector<std::function<void(std::string)>> v;
v.push_back(f);
v.push_back(g);
v.push_back(h);
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned each lambda you declare has unique context specific type even if it has seemingly identical signature. This is why vector of lambdas has only theoretical value - you would be able to push there at most one lambda... You have two choices - you could go along with proposed approach from other answers and store lambdas into a type-erasure `std::function` before putting them into vector or put your lambdas into a "container" that would collect the type of each element apart from the lambda object itself - `std::tuple`:

```
auto t = std::make_tuple([](){ std::cout<<"First lambda" << std::endl; },
                         [](){ std::cout<<"Second lambda"<< std::endl; },
                         [](){ std::cout<<"Third lambda" << std::endl; });
```

and get appropriate lambda at compile-time:

```
std::get<0>(t)(); // the value in get must be known at compile time! 
                  // otherwise compiler won't be able to establish type 
                  // of lambda and the whole point of using tuple is lost
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uKdD1ROvlmy4VvFi)