# Can I store bound functions in a container?

Tags: c++, boost-bind

Consider the following code:

```
void func_0()
{
    std::cout << "Zero parameter function" << std::endl;
}

void func_1(int i)
{
    std::cout << "One parameter function [" << i << "]" << std::endl;
}

void func_2(int i, std::string s)
{
    std::cout << "One parameter function [" << i << ", " << s << "]" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto f0 = boost::bind(func_0);
    auto f1 = boost::bind(func_1,10);
    auto f2 = boost::bind(func_2,20,"test");

    f0();
    f1();
    f2();
}
```

The above code works as intended. Is there any way I can store f0, f1, f2 in a container and execute it like this:

```
Container cont; // stores all the bound functions.
for(auto func : cont)
{
    func();
}
```

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128444/c-calling-a-function-from-a-vector-of-function-pointers-inside-a-class-where-t

Comment: No, that is very different. I am talking about bound functions here.

Comment: Is there a reason you use `boost::bind` instead of `std::bind`? The usage of `auto` indicates that there would be no need for using boost anymore.

Comment: I can use either bind. I used auto just for convenience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this example work for you?

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> container{f0, f1, f2};
for (auto& func : container)
{
    func();
}
```

You can [read here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) about std::function:

> Instances of std::function can store, copy, and invoke any Callable
>   target ...

So the template argument for this class template (`void()` in our case) is merely the signature of the *Callable*. What `bind()` returned in all your calls to it is exactly a *Callable* of the form `void()`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::bind` is not guaranteed to return the same type for functions with the same final interface (final = after binding). So, no, you won't be able to store functions bound with `std::bind` in a container. You will have to use some sort of type-erasure technique to bring them all to the same type, like `std::function`. A container of `std::function<void()>` will be able to store your bound functions (at the expense of type-erasure-related overhead).

I don't know whether it applies to `boost::bind`, but I suspect it is the same as `std::bind` in that regard.